# Find all real numbers $x$ such that $x[x[x[x]]]=88$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes floor function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:** Find the all real numbers $x$ such that $x[x[x[x]]]=88$ where $[\cdot ]$ denotes floor function.

**Attempt:** $$x[x[x[x]]]=88\implies [x[x[x]]]=\frac{88}{x}.$$
Since left side of equation always gives an integer value, $88$ has to be divisible by $x$. 
Also, $3^4=81$. So the solution should lie between $3$ and $4$.

Comment: $x$ doesn't have to be an integer just because $88/x$ is, but it does greatly decrease the number of possible options. There are only finitely many between $3$ and $4$.

Comment: There is a solution, but it's not an integer. $\frac{88}x$ is an integer, though.

Comment: OK. I think there is only one solution and its near 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculation of $x$ in $x \lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor = 88$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488120/calculation-of-x-in-x-lfloor-x-lfloor-x-lfloor-x-rfloor-rfloor-rfloor-88)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the given equation basically implies $x^4\approx88$, and we know $\frac{88}x$ is an integer. Now, if $x^4\approx88$, then $x\approx\sqrt[4]{88}=3.063$, and then $\frac{88}x\approx28.732$. So I'd guess either $\frac{88}x=28$ or $\frac{88}x=29$. That is, I'd guess either $x=\frac{88}{28}=\frac{22}7$ or $x=\frac{88}{29}$. No guarantees that one of them works, though.

We *do* know there's at most one solution, since $x\lfloor x\lfloor x\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\rfloor$ is an increasing function.

Comment: 88/27 is the answer given in my book.

Comment: @AdityaDev Really? [Wolfram Alpha says otherwise](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+floor%28x+floor%28x+floor%28x%29%29%29+where+x%3D88%2F27). I'm pretty sure that $88/28=22/7$ should be the answer; perhaps it was a typo?

Comment: Typo.... It's 88/28